# External JavaScript and Dropdown Menu not Properly Rendering in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I am trying to make a dropdown menu that calls uses an external Javascript function/file and alternates the picture according to the user's selection but for some reason the picture won't change. The dropdown menu shows up as well as the default image since that is hard-coded in but the pictures aren't changing. This is my very first time using JavaScript so I'm sure it is full of errors but any help would be appreciated. I really have no idea what I am doing

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>All Seasons</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src = "allseasons.js"></script>
  <img id="myimage" src="winter.jpg" alt="current season." />
  <select name="seasons">
    <option>
      Winter
      <button onclick="changepic('winter')"></button>
    </option>
    <option>
      Spring
      <button onclick="changepic('spring')"></button>
    </option>
    <option>
      Summer
      <button onclick="changepic('summer')"></button>
    </option>
    <option>
      Fall
      <button onclick="changepic('fall')"></button>
    </option>
  </select>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function changepic(season){
    switch (season){
        case 'winter': document.getElementById('myimage').src='winter.jpg';
        break;

        case 'spring': document.getElementById('myimage').src='spring.jpg';
        break;

        case 'summer': document.getElementById('myimage').src='summer.jpg';
        break;

        case 'fall': document.getElementById('myimage').src='fall.jpg';
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Your `img` doesn't have an ID of `myimage`. You need to assing it one like `<img id="myimage">`

Comment: @ShekharChikara I fixed that but it is still not switching the images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best practice to have your `<script>` tags inside the `<head></head>`

With native Javascript you can do it like this:

```js
function changepic(season) {
  switch (season) {
    case 'winter': document.getElementById('myimage').src='https://s1.postimg.org/40ndqhnyfv/image.jpg';
    break;
    
    case 'spring': document.getElementById('myimage').src='https://s1.postimg.org/85iz2llc8b/image.jpg';
    break;

    case 'summer': document.getElementById('myimage').src='https://s1.postimg.org/40ndqhnyfv/image.jpg';
    break;

    case 'fall': document.getElementById('myimage').src='https://s1.postimg.org/85iz2llc8b/image.jpg';
    break;      
  }

  console.log('Current image is : ' + document.getElementById('myimage').src);
}
```

```html
<img id="myimage" src="https://s1.postimg.org/40ndqhnyfv/image.jpg" id="myimage"/>
<select name="seasons" onChange="changepic(this.value)">
    <option value="winter">Winter</option>
    <option value="spring">Spring</option>
    <option value="summer">Summer</option>
    <option value="fall">Fall</option>
</select>
```

Make sure that images are in the same folder with the script or if they are in another directory that the path is correct

Comment: Thank you so much @Chrysovalantis Koutsoumpos! However the pictures are still not changing. All files are in the same directory and have the same extension. Is there something  we are missing?

Comment: I have updated the code with some original images in order to prove that is is working correctly. The is something wrong with your images. Make sure that the names and the endings are correct OR use the full path

Comment: Got it! I had to move the script tag as you suggested. I really can't thank you enough for all of your help!

Comment: I am glad that I could help. You can help me gain some points by up-voting my correct answers

Answer (score 1):

Putting buttons inside a select dropdown option is not recommended for such things. You should listen for [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event on your `select` element and do your processing there. Inside the change function, you can easily get access to the `option` selected in the dropdown by adding `value` attribute to all the options.

So your code with the `change` event will look like below -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#seasonsDropdown').change(function() {
    var seasonValue = document.getElementById('seasonsDropdown').value;
    switch(seasonValue) {
      case 'winter': document.getElementById('myimage').src='winter.jpg';
      break;

      case 'spring': document.getElementById('myimage').src='spring.jpg';
      break;

      case 'summer': document.getElementById('myimage').src='summer.jpg';
      break;

      case 'fall': document.getElementById('myimage').src='fall.jpg';
      break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "allseasons.js"></script>
<img id="myimage" src="winter.jpg" alt="current season." />
<select name="seasons" id="seasonsDropdown">
    <option value="winter">Winter</option>
    <option value="spring">Spring</option>
    <option value="summer">Summer</option>
    <option value="fall">Fall</option>
</select>
```